# Classes of methods in ruby

Tags: ruby

In furthering my study of Ruby, I've noticed that some methods really seem to give power to the language, while others are just syntactic sugar.

Examples of sugar: .split, .strip, i.e. any methods that just make doing a menial task with a data structure easier.

Examples of power methods: call, send, responds_to?, method_missing, etc.

It seems like if you understand those "power methods" you really know the language.

Curious about three things:

1. Has anyone every made such a distinction, be it in a book/blog post etc?
2. Do you personally make such a distinction?
3. If you feel what I'm saying is correct, what "power methods" should I know and use better?

Thanks (hope this question doesn't get closed!)

Comment: Best place for this question is - https://www.ruby-forum.com/forum/ruby .. Here in SO you might be having risk in keeping it open.. :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by power methods. If you mean the meta methods, there's some books you can refer to about metaprogramming in ruby

Answer (score 2):

These aren't really "power methods" but are just another tool in the toolbox that is the Ruby library.

Methods like `call` and `send` are for low-level operations, bypassing the usual Ruby semantic layer. `responds_to?` is often used when writing generic code that uses [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), and `method_missing` is a way of writing code that responds to a variety of methods in a dynamic way. This is how Rails ActiveRecord handles methods calls like `find_by_name_or_phone` automatically.

Methods like `split`, `strip` and `chomp` are simply data transformation methods. Their primary function is to convert one thing into another, optionally in-place.

I don't think there's a distinction between any of these methods, they're all quite useful, but they do have their particular uses. As far as Ruby is concerned, though, all methods are equal, there's no hierarchy or inherent importance to them.

Some methods you will use very infrequently, so you're less likely to ever have need for them unless you've done a lot of Ruby.

Comment: And 'method_missing' is a bad style.

Comment: @CodeGroover I disagree. I think that depends on what you're using it for. I agree though that using it for `find_by_name_or_phone` is probably bad style.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However I should clarify, I know that in the language itself, all of these are equal methods. I more meant in terms of "using power methods indicates you better understand the language". Has anyone made such a distinction and if so have they listed out those methods?

Comment: In any language there are methods that are called very often, some that are called infrequently, and some very rarely. The rare ones are usually an indication you're doing something more "advanced" but aren't a reliable guide. Using them deliberately doesn't make you a better programmer, and some great programmers never really have to use those methods.